# Como alinhar ao centro o conteúdo de um card?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

O card contém um ícone e um título.

Pretendo alinhar ambos no centro (horizontalmente e verticalmente). Não basta usar a classe `text-center`?

```
<div class="card bg-green p-1 w-100" style='height:12em'>
    <div class="mt-3 icon text-center">
      {{post.icon}} 
    </div>
    
    <div class="card-body title text-center">
        <h5 class="card-title"> 
          {% if post.size %}
          <span style="font-size:{{post.size}} text size big">{{post.title}}</span>
          {%else %}
          {{post.title}} {{post.subtitle}}
          {% endif %}
        </h5>
    </div>
```